# Как повысить приоритет условия в .tpl?

Tags: smarty, веб-дизайн, шаблонизаторы

Прошу помочь разобраться. 
Есть интернет-магазин с огромным количеством страниц и заполненными на них мета-тегами (description,title) 
Появилась необходимость изменить мета-теги только на паре определенных страницах. Пробую сделать условием через код:

```html
{if $page->url=='/catalog/elektricheskie-teplye-poly/brand-devi'}
{$meta_description = "Мы предлагаем купить теплый пол devi, цена на который у нас одна из самых низких, чтобы купить теплый пол деви, звоните по телефону: ☎ 8(3822) 44-33-55"}
{/if}
  
{if (!empty($meta_description) || !empty($meta_keywords) || !empty($filter_meta->description) || !empty($filter_meta->keywords)) && !$smarty.get.page}

    <meta name="description" content="{$meta_description|escape}{$filter_meta->description|escape}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{$meta_keywords|escape}{$filter_meta->keywords|escape}">
{/if}
```

Но условие это работает только на страницах, где нет мета-тегов вообще. На страницах, где есть мета-теги выводятся прежние, которые прописаны видимо где-то еще.

Как возможно повысить приоритет, чтобы выводились мета-теги которые я прописываю в коде при условии, а не те, которые есть в административной панели?

Пожалуйста, не пишите такие варианты, как заменить эти мета-теги в админке. Хочется разобраться именно с этим методом.

Comment: добавьте в код переменную(boolean), если она в значении `true` то выводите свои значения meta, если `false` тогда из базы.

Comment: зачем у вас условия для keywords и description одним блоком написаны? разделите  их на два

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, все это надо сократить до вида

```
{$keywords = "новые ключевые слова"}
<meta name="keywords" content="{$keywords|default:$filter_meta->keywords|escape}"/>
```

В таком виде будут использованы либо назначенные, если их нет, то из CMS видимо, или пустые.
Для `description` поступить аналогично. В любом случае, объединять условия для `keywords` и `description` в один `if` не надо, это мало того, что не читаемо, дак еще и непонятно

Если уж совсем не хочется выводить пустой тэг, когда слов нет, то

```
{$keywords = "Новые слова"|default:$filter_meta->keywords}
{if $keywords}
    <meta name="keywords" content="{$keywords|escape}">
{/if}
```

сюда же можно дописать странное условие про `$smarty.get.page`

Если же вам надо сначала вывести назначенные слова, потом из базы, то тоже  просто

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{$keywords} {$meta_filter->keywords|escape}"/>
```

смысла какого-либо ветвления нет.

Comment: попробовал по вашему варианту, тогда он абсолютно на всех страницах выводит «Новые слова» и все мета-теги получаются одинаковые. Наверное или я вас не понял или вы меня. Необходимо чтобы все было как есть сейчас,все теги остались как есть, но лишь на двух страницах например: (/dostavka и /oplata) были мета-теги мои, которые я сам здесь пропишу и они перебивали теги, которые уже прописаны только для этих страниц в CMS.

Comment: @RangerNicholas ну дак `if`-ы то свои с условиями на ссылки добавьте в код `{if .....}{$keywords = "..."}{/if}`

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Ошибка в условии проверки адреса страницы. Вот рабочий код.

```html
//Проверяем url страницы,если страница, которая нам нужна то выводятся наши заданные мета-теги
 
{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI == "/catalog/bimetallicheskie-radiatory-otopleniya/brand-rifarbase"}
   {$meta_title = "Радиаторы отопления рифар - цена в интернет-магазине «Реоком»"}
   {$meta_description = "Мы предлагаем купить радиаторы отопления рифар,звоните по телефону"}
{/if}
 
 
//Затем если у страницы пустые мета-теги выводим уже присвоенные
 
{if (!empty($meta_description) || !empty($meta_keywords) || !empty($filter_meta->description) || !empty($filter_meta->keywords)) && !$smarty.get.page}
    <meta name="description" content="{$meta_description|escape}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{$meta_keywords|escape}{$filter_meta->keywords|escape}">
{/if}
```